# Signature invalid only for ad hoc

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm not sure what changed on my ad hocs but I get this error when trying to install:

Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Device debug builds fine. The cert that is associated with my ad hoc provisioning profile doesn't expire until 2011. I've searched Google but haven't found any applicable solution, except some mention about deleting and recreating the certs. Before I go down that rode, has any one experienced and resolved this issue?

I'm using Xcode 3.2.3 and building against sdk 3.0.

Comment: Deleting and reinstalling the profile in iTunes is just drag and drop.  I would re download the profile and the go that route.  I've had this happen before and actually a restart fixed the issue... try that first.

Comment: I've re downloaded the profile but xcode still gives this same warning after building.

Comment: Actually, this is working now, even with xcode still giving the validation error on the ad hoc build.  Put it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I get this issue as well. Do you have any expired profiles on your phone? I find that sometimes expired profiles (even if it is for a different application) will cause debug builds to not install.

If all else fails, delete all the certificates associated with your developer account from Apple in Keychain Access. Get yourself a new certificate, and modify the provisioning profiles to reflect the new certificate. This is a huge pain, but if all else fails, this works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've the above and it works for me (the developer) but not for someone else, although it use to work fine.